# Customize oauth2 requested scopes

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

My usecase is to customize oauth2 scopes that the user has requested and grant the user only filtered ones,
Eg : User1 wants to generate token, his ldap role is R1 ,and i have a mapping table of R1->read,write
So i want this user to get only the mapped scopes, regardless of the requested scope.

I am trying to add a filter in @EnableWebSecurity class :

`@Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.addFilterAfter(new OAuth2UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) }`

But when i call the /oauth/token API , the attemptAuthentication method is not getting called , it gets called if i put any other api except the /oauth/generate
My OAuth2UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

.Does any one has a better solution to restrict requested scopes by intercepting the request ?Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The user doesn't get any scopes, it is a client feature. The user can grant scopes for a particular client. If you want to restrict the scopes for a client you could change the client registration.

Comment: By user getting scopes i mean the final scopes generated after generating the token for a username and password.
My problem is solved now , i used custom token enhancer and fetched the role-scope mapping . After that i limited the token`s scope to the filtered scope list . Thanks